# sqlalchemy query result is empty when passed into jinja2template form element

Tags: html, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I am trying to get a grip on the subject. Have a simple signup form with a dropdown list for customers. While rendering this form I am trying to pass the results of a sql query as a parameter. A debug print before passing, shows that correct result was returned from the query but when it goes in the form the dropdown list is not populating with the value of the list.

Am I not passing it correctly?

Here's the code samples.

The relevant part of main.py where the query is executed and the value list_of_customers is passed in the TemplateResponse():

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, APIRouter, Depends, Form, HTTPException, Response
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

from starlette.templating import Jinja2Templates
from starlette.responses import RedirectResponse

from connection import Base, engine, sess_db

from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.sql import text


@app.get("/user/signup")
def signup(req: Request, db: Session = Depends(sess_db)):
    list_of_customers = db.execute(text("SELECT name FROM resichain.customers ORDER BY name ASC"))
    return templates.TemplateResponse("signup.html",
                                          context={'request': req,
                                                   'list_of_customers': list_of_customers}
                                      )
```

Then in the signup.html this list_of_customers is iterated to populate the dropdown list for the customer selection as such:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block main %}
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <form action="/signupuser" method="post">
            <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
                <p class="lead fw-normal mb-2 me-3">CREATE AN ACCOUNT</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                <select name="customer" id="customer" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                    {% for customer in list_of_customers %}
                        <option value={{customer}}>{{customer}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <label class="form-label" for="customer">Customer Name</label>
             </div>
         </form>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

When I check the form the dropdown is empty.

Comment: You query result is effectively an iterator, so printing it may have exhausted the iterator, leaving nothing to iterate over in the template.  The result will yield single element tuples, which might also potentially be a problem.  `list_of_customers = db.scalars(text(...)).all()` might work around both issues: it will return a list, not an iterator, and each element will be a string rather than a tuple.

Comment: Thank you @snakecharmerb for pointing out the root of the problem and also for the solution to handle it. It worked just at it should be.